# Setting up an ark server through google cloud ubuntu?

Tags: server, steam, ark

I am using ubuntu 16 and I believe I have the steam files installed and even made a launch script. The server launches and it then seems to not do anything else. I am doing this on google cloud with the 300$ free credit. I suppose what I'm asking is has anyone set up an ark server on google cloud ubuntu and could said person give me guidance on why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been reading the Google Compute instances don't support the appropriate GPU passthrough to enable game streaming. Their instances are optimized for rendering and calculations and don't have the right setup for gaming yet (no monitor/output attachment).